# DAX Subtract Fixed Values from Year or Quarter in a Matrix

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Need to subtract a set value from year and quarter aggregates in a Matrix visual for Chrysler. Data is by month for multiple years, need to make a fixed adjustment to **Chrysler only** of 5 for **each quarter** and 15 for **each year** without the total going below zero.

**Expected Result:**

| Date | Aston Martin | BMW | Chrysler | Grand Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **2020** | 0 | 27.36 | **26.22** | 53.58 |
| Qtr1 | 0 | 0 | 7.99 | 7.99 |
| Qtr2 | 0 | 17.34 | 9.15 | 26.49 |
| Qtr3 | 0 | 10.02 | 0 | 10.02 |
| Qtr4 | 0 | 0 | 7.53 | 7.53 |
| **2021** | 10.05 | 51.51 | **7.32** | 68.88 |
| Qtr1 | 0 | 18.45 | 0 | 18.45 |
| Qtr2 | 0 | 13.77 | 0 | 13.77 |
| Qtr3 | 10.05 | 4.44 | 12.51 | 27 |
| Qtr4 | 0 | 14.85 | 0 | 14.85 |
| **2022** | 18.14 | 53.52 | **4.08** | 75.74 |
| Qtr1 | 18.14 | 17.64 | 0 | 35.78 |
| Qtr2 | 0 | 21.77 | 0 | 21.77 |
| Qtr3 | 0 | 7.44 | 3.73 | 11.17 |
| Qtr4 | 0 | 6.67 | 1.08 | 7.75 |
| **Grand Total** | 28.19 | 132.39 | **37.62** | 198.2 |

**Data:**

| id | Group | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Chrysler | 7/30/2021 | 8.88 |
| 9 | Chrysler | 9/16/2021 | 3.16 |
| 18 | BMW | 5/26/2022 | 5.76 |
| 69 | Chrysler | 1/9/2020 | 6.14 |
| 75 | BMW | 3/20/2021 | 4.33 |
| 84 | BMW | 6/20/2020 | 8.97 |
| 104 | BMW | 10/22/2021 | 4.91 |
| 113 | Aston Martin | 3/5/2022 | 5.61 |
| 119 | Chrysler | 10/22/2022 | 6.08 |
| 139 | BMW | 9/13/2020 | 8.33 |
| 140 | Chrysler | 8/11/2020 | 1.55 |
| 169 | BMW | 3/2/2021 | 6.97 |
| 206 | BMW | 5/13/2021 | 4.34 |
| 244 | Chrysler | 11/10/2020 | 8.45 |
| 247 | Chrysler | 12/18/2020 | 2.38 |
| 284 | BMW | 2/4/2022 | 0.73 |
| 289 | BMW | 10/26/2022 | 2.24 |
| 383 | Aston Martin | 2/21/2022 | 7.61 |
| 400 | Chrysler | 4/5/2020 | 9.34 |
| 402 | Chrysler | 9/11/2022 | 1.63 |
| 403 | BMW | 5/27/2020 | 8.37 |
| 414 | Chrysler | 8/11/2021 | 4.93 |
| 441 | BMW | 2/21/2022 | 9.5 |
| 533 | Chrysler | 9/18/2022 | 7.1 |
| 538 | BMW | 1/28/2021 | 7.15 |
| 556 | BMW | 6/30/2022 | 4.61 |
| 586 | BMW | 5/2/2022 | 1.44 |
| 672 | BMW | 10/16/2022 | 2.21 |
| 734 | BMW | 2/15/2022 | 6.74 |
| 736 | Chrysler | 6/16/2020 | 4.81 |
| 740 | BMW | 12/5/2022 | 2.22 |
| 755 | BMW | 9/14/2021 | 4.44 |
| 766 | BMW | 4/14/2021 | 9.43 |
| 781 | Aston Martin | 8/14/2021 | 6.46 |
| 784 | Chrysler | 12/30/2021 | 4.81 |
| 788 | BMW | 5/17/2022 | 4.4 |
| 815 | Aston Martin | 8/29/2021 | 3.59 |
| 816 | Aston Martin | 3/17/2022 | 4.92 |
| 831 | BMW | 3/24/2022 | 0.67 |
| 835 | BMW | 11/28/2021 | 9.94 |
| 844 | Chrysler | 8/17/2021 | 0.54 |
| 849 | BMW | 8/26/2022 | 7.43 |
| 861 | BMW | 7/24/2020 | 1.69 |
| 885 | Chrysler | 1/11/2022 | 4.27 |
| 911 | BMW | 7/1/2022 | 0.01 |
| 942 | Chrysler | 12/26/2020 | 1.7 |
| 946 | BMW | 6/9/2022 | 5.56 |
| 948 | Chrysler | 3/13/2020 | 6.85 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming: you have a date table (not necessarily marked as a date table) with a YearQuarter column, a Groups table with keys for each of the groups, and a simple measure like SumValue in the Table table.

```
(Measure on Table table)
SumValue := SUM('Table'[Value])

(Measure on Table table)
CustomChrysler := 
VAR YearQuarterGroup = 
    CROSSJOIN( 
        VALUES( Dates[YearQuarter] ),VALUES( Groups[Group] ) 
        )
VAR Result = 
SUMX(
    YearQuarterGroup, 
    VAR SumVal = [SumValue]
    VAR Amount = IF( Groups[Group] = "Chrysler", SumVal - 5, SumVal )
    VAR AmountGreaterThanZero = IF( Amount < 0, 0, Amount )
    RETURN
    AmountGreaterThanZero
    )
RETURN Result
```

[image]

Update:
Which one?

[image]

```
CustomChrysler2 := 
VAR YearQuarterGroup = 
    CROSSJOIN( 
        VALUES( Dates[YearQuarter] ),VALUES( Groups[Group] ) 
        )
VAR YearGroup = 
    CROSSJOIN( 
        VALUES( Dates[Year] ),VALUES( Groups[Group] ) 
        )
VAR ResulYearQuarter = 
SUMX(
    YearQuarterGroup, 
    VAR SumVal = [SumValue]
    VAR Amount = IF( Groups[Group] = "Chrysler", SumVal - 5, SumVal )
    VAR AmountGreaterthanZero = IF( Amount >= 0, Amount) //BLANK
    //VAR AmountGreaterThanZero = IF( Amount < 0, 0, Amount ) //Zero
    RETURN
    AmountGreaterThanZero
    )
VAR ResultYear = 
SUMX(
    YearGroup, 
    VAR SumVal = [SumValue]
    VAR Amount = IF( Groups[Group] = "Chrysler", SumVal - 15, SumVal )
    VAR AmountGreaterthanZero = IF( Amount >= 0, Amount) //BLANK
    //VAR AmountGreaterThanZero = IF( Amount < 0, 0, Amount ) //Zero
    RETURN
    AmountGreaterThanZero
    )
RETURN 
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    ISINSCOPE(Dates[Quarter]), ResulYearQuarter,
    ResultYear //ISINSCOPE(Dates[Year]) and Grand Total
    )
```

Comment: This is great, but I also need -15 for each year without the total going below zero. Two separate calcs: -5 per quarter and -15 per year without going below zero

Comment: My question and possible clarification for someone else who wants to collaborate:
At the year level, should I subtract 15 from the SUM without changes? I mean, the result for Chrysler in 2020 should be 41.22 - 15 = 26.22(?)

Comment: You are correct with 26.22, I fixed the result

Comment: What would be the definition of Grand Total? The [Year] level no longer represents the sum of the modified values at the [Quarter] level. I mean, how should the Grand Total be calculated?

Comment: Sum of modified [Year] would be the grand total

Comment: Edited just now.